# Resize parent layout + keep children elements fixed in their position on Nativescript + Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Let's consider these two layers:

```
<AbsoluteLayout ref="big" width="500" height="500" >
    <AbsoluteLayout ref="small" width="100" height="100" >
        ....
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

1. I want to resize `big`;
2. I need to keep `small` fixed in its initial position; ( ***The Actual Problem*** )

but `small` responses to the `big` resizing!

How can I solve this?

Comment: This more looks like a css problem. 
Using position absolute or fixed, should fix the issue.

You can post more info what directions you are going to resize parent

Comment: as much as I know there is no FIXED position property in NS, since we need to deal with Layout instead of DIV or so.

I am asking this question in general, to found out a proper way to solve such these problems, cause it would be very handy.